# Por que não temos um Inteiro de 128 bits?

Tags: característica-linguagem, tipagem, int

Nós temos valores inteiros de 16, 32 e 64 bits. `short`, `int` e `long`, respectivamente. Mas por que não temos inteiros de 128? Ou de 256?

Pergunto isso para um caso de precisarmos guardar um número extremamente grande, que não caiba na notação que conhecemos hoje.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit

Comment: Em VHDL eu tinha ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Uma curiosidade: o Numbers.app, o Excel da Apple, utiliza um motor de cálculo 128 bits desde a última versão

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basicamente porque é raro ter necessidade. Problemas reais não precisam de números tão grandes. Para os raros casos onde se precisa de um número tão grande já costuma ser melhor trabalhar com um tipo que tenha total elasticidade como o [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do C# ou [do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Este tipo tem a vantagem de não ter estouro, você pode começar pequeno e crescer sem problemas. Claro que ele ocupa mais espaço e é menos eficiente. Se precisa disto, use-o. Ele permite qualquer número representável por um ser humano e que cabe em um computador.

Basicamente é escolha pragmática da linguagem não poluir com algo pouco necessário. Provavelmente este tipo seria considerado primitivo ou algo parecido na linguagem e aí teria que lidar com ele em muitos lugares, fica complicado.

Um motivo colateral secundário e pouco importante é que os processadores não trabalham diretamente nas instruções mais simples com tantos bits. Mas nem é importante porque mesmo o tipo de 64 bits tinha e tem esse problema em algumas arquiteturas, o mesmo vale para outros números. Existem arquiteturas que suportam isso, mas não são comuns e não fazem processamento básico que CPUs costumam fazer. Um motivo para elas evitarem isto também é que o processador seria construído muito maior para apenas trabalhar com esses números e não usaria tudo isso para endereçamento, o que seria um custo muito alto para pouco uso e ganho. Mas novamente, este não é o principal motivo de não ter esse tipo.

Por outro lado, nada impede alguém de criar um tipo assim se for muito importante para você, a maioria das linguagens permitem isso de uma forma melhor ou pior, até Java vai permitir, de um jeito não muito pior, e em geral todas aceitam de um jeito pior. Um tipo assim teria que ser composto por 2 valores de 64 bits na maioria das arquiteturas e fazer o devido tratamento para sempre dar o resultado esperado.

Não tem a ver com inteiros, mas temos um tipo com 128 bits (tecnicamente 96 são usados para representar grandeza, ou 97 se considerar o sinal como parte da grandeza, o resto é usado para representar escala e reservado para futuras implementações), só que ele não é inteiro é [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), o que não impede de ser usado como um inteiro também, só não é garantido.

E sendo importante para alguns, foi criado o tipo [`Int128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e agora está oficialmente no .NET 7.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).